# wchar_t strings not working C

Tags: c, string, wchar-t

I'm trying to create a program that needs to get string input from the user, since it's has to work with portuguese words i'm using wchar_t,the problem is,
C seems to have a will, because when i need it to work it doens't but then out of the blue it works in some simple test.
the following code worked 5 minutes ago and now it doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
/
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    wchar_t meu[3];
    fgetws(meu,3,stdin);
    fputws(meu,stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you put output for both cases; the case where it worked and the case where it didn't?

Comment: That's the thing, it's the same code, it worked and then I went to look my main program and see if there were any differences on how i used wchar, and when i went back and runned the code again it didn't work.

Comment: i want the code to read for example "çá" and print it normally, it work with ASCII characters, but not with the wide characters it should work

Comment: You should check the value returned by `setlocale`. It is possible that the locale you requested may not have been set.

Comment: 1)  Check return value from all 3 function calls. 2) `"çá\n"` is too big for `wchar_t meu[3];`

Comment: even if i increase n in wchar_t meu[n] and continue to pass "çá\n" it doesn't work

Comment: Show what operating system you use, and what compiler. The question has been asked before.

Comment: windows 8.1 single language and i use falcon

Comment: What are the return values of the function calls?  If something is not working, one of them is probably failing.  Knowing what is failing is pretty fundamental to debugging the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, to as far as I know fgetws and fputws don't return anything. I'm sorry i'm new to c. I've tried initializing the string explicitly and using the fputws, and it did'nt work.but the fgetws could also not be working

Comment: I don't know this compiler but it probably won't work, unless you use WinAPI directly. If you are on a Portuguese computer then you should be able to type in Portuguese and use `char`, Windows should use the ANSI version (it may not be compatible with other platforms). If it still doesn't work then call `SetConsoleOutputCP` and `SetConsoleCP` with Portuguese code page.